# Backup SQLite using Java

Tags: java, sqlite, backup

I need to create a Java class that creates a backup of my database. My problem is, I don't know how to do this using a SQLite database. Can anyone show me how?

Comment: perhaps this addresses what you want https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/Usage.md

Answer (score 4):

If the database is reasonably small, you can just call `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION` to [prevent other processes from modifying the database](http://sqlite.com/lang_transaction.html), then copy the database file, then `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. If the file is huge, you'll have  to use the [online backup interface](http://sqlite.com/backup.html) (if your Java bindings don't support it, use JNI).

Of course, if there's just your app using this database and you can be sure that nobody's going to modify the file while you're copying it, just go for it and copy.

Comment: Much better answer than mine- thanks! Didn't know about exclusive transactions either.

Comment: But if someone else has already started a transaction I will fail, right?

Comment: PRAGMA busy_timeout = milliseconds; can help in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to create a copy of the database file- assuming it is a disk-based DB.

Comment: Deffinately the easiest and probably best option, since SQLite is a single file database.  I had written my won answer but no point keeping it as you beat me to it lol.