# From in-memory database to disk

Tags: java, sqlite

I am inserting into an SQLite in-memory database with Java. When a specific condition is encountered I need to empty it after copying its content to a disk-based database. And then start populating the in-memory database again.

How can I achieve this using Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245244/backup-sqlite-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BACKUP TO` in SQLite:

```java
public static void store(Connection connection, Path destination) throws SQLException {
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate("BACKUP TO " + destination.toAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```